# How to use lamda and an if in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use the lambda function to calculate some pay rates depending on job type.

Here is part of my code:

```
Payrate = {
'NH': 14.00,
'W1': 14.00,
'W2': 14.00,
'W3': 14.00,
'M': 14.00,
'NHLC': 14.00,
'E': 14.00,
}

df = df.fillna(0)
df['Total shift hours'] = df['Total shift hours'].astype(int)

df['Hours'] = df['Job'].apply(lambda x: x[Payrate] if x[Payrate]*(x['Total shift hours'])/12.33 else df['Total shift hours'].sum()).round(2)
```

`Job` is a column in the data frame that shows us the job type. So what I'm trying to say is, if the Job type matches the jobs in `Payrate`, multiply the `Total shift hours` by assigned value of 14 and divide it by 12.33. Else, if it's another job type that's not mentioned in the `Payrate` dict, take the sum of `Total shift hours`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: your if statement is incorrect? what are you testing also use `np.where`

Comment: The syntax of 'if' in lambda is 'then-branch if condition else else-branch'. Right now you have then-branch and condition swapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution without loop in `apply` by mapping in [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with replace missing not matched values by `sum`:

```
df['Hours'] = ((df['Job'].map(Payrate) * df['Total shift hours'] / 12.33 )
                  .fillna(df['Total shift hours'].sum()).round(2))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, I've actually got the calculation wrong. I only need the values in dict to be multiplied by 14 and then divided by 12.33. Otherwise, I would just like the `Total shift hours` to be summed up per courier name. Sorry for the confusion! Would your solution still work if I replaced it with `fillna.(df['Total shift hours'].sum())`?

Comment: @cchev - answer was edited.

Comment: thanks for responding so quickly and sorry for the confusion!